# spring boot admin remote registration not working

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I have successfully deployed spring boot admin and registered client spring boot apps with the following client configs.

`working configuration`

```
pom.xml dependency:
 <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
 </dependency>

application.properties entry:
#Spring boot admin client config

spring.boot.admin.client.url=http://localhost:8080
spring.boot.admin.client.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.info.env.enabled=true
spring.boot.admin.client.auto-registration=true
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

Now with the exact same configuration I have deployed spring boot admin server to different host but the client application is not getting registered with the following application.properties :
We have two instances of same app running one two different servers with same config.

```
application.properties entry:
#Spring boot admin client config

spring.boot.admin.client.url=http://remote-host-name:8080
spring.boot.admin.client.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.info.env.enabled=true
spring.boot.admin.client.auto-registration=true
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

Kindly help. I could never find a remote spring boot admin remote deployment example.

Now with the exact same configuration I have deployed spring boot admin server to different host but the client application is not getting registered with the following application.properties :
We have two instances of same app running one two different servers with same config.

```
application.properties entry:
#Spring boot admin client config

spring.boot.admin.client.url=http://remote-host-name:8080
spring.boot.admin.client.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.info.env.enabled=true
spring.boot.admin.client.auto-registration=true
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

Kindly help. I could never find a remote spring boot admin remote deployment example.